# Why are these assignments to java.lang.Exception type safe?

Tags: scala

Why do statements below not cause compiler type errors :

```
val y1: Int = throw new Exception("fail!")
val y2: Boolean = throw new Exception("fail!")
val y3: String = throw new Exception("fail!")
val y4: List[Any] = throw new Exception("fail!")
val y5 : java.lang.Exception = throw new Exception("fail!")
```

just the type `y5` is of type `java.lang.Exception` so expect it to be type safe but why is `y1,y2,y3,y4` also type safe ? They should all be of type `java.lang.exception` ?

Comment: because throw returns Nothing, which is a subclass of everything. none of these declarations gets assigned an object, because none of them return normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [API doc for Nothing](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Nothing) says:

> Another usage for Nothing is the return type for methods which never return normally. One example is method error in scala.sys, which always throws an exception.

Here throw does not return the Exception, it is one of these methods that never return normally. Returning Nothing keeps the compiler happy because Nothing is the bottom type (a subclass of everything else), and assigning an instance of a subclass is ok. Of course the assignment never actually happens because the exception gets thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment never completes, because you throw before getting there. So it's completely typesafe:

```
val y1: Int = throw new Exception("fail!")
y1 * 25
```

There won't be a type error on line 2, because you never get to line 2; the exception breaks out of the whole function before that. So `y1` can be any type and it will still be typesafe.

If you tried to assign an exception, `val y1: Int = new Exception("fail!")`, that would be an error, and the value would indeed have to have type `Exception`.